# Are there any (theoretical-esque) computer science "competitions" at Undergrad level similar to Putnam?

Tags: theory, programming-contest

I have searched for a bit eventually arriving at well known websites like codeforces, atcoder, codewars, codinggame or the various OJs.
They mostly involve solving tasks where usually the main focus is elementary discrete maths + data structures and algorithms.

However, I cannot find any that target the more theoretical side of Computer Science with topics including Complexity, Theory of Computation, Logic, Algorithms, Probability & Linear Algebra questions etc.

So do such contests exists? If so, please list!
Bonus if there are any contests for high schoolers as well.

Comment: What do you mean by Logic and proof based algorithms?Programs are algorithms,by implementtion by hand,do you mean conjecturing an algorithm and then proving it to be correct?

Comment: @DeepakGupta For a lack of better problems, please refer to Chapter VII of CLRS  and see the back exercises. Some of them illustrate what I mean by "Algorithms" here. I have edited the question to remove the ambiguity.

For Logic, I meant problems on propositional logic, first-order logic and related topics (i.e, at not so in-depth part of logic)

Comment: I'm a little surprised that no one has mentioned project Euler.  It's not exactly a competition per se, but a set of problems that require both math and computer science.  As the website says, "Project Euler is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require more than just mathematical insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming skills will be required to solve most problems."  I think it requires good algorithm design, some probability, and some logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that I found was the from the Indian based college(?) Chennai Mathematical Institute (CMI)'s [STEM's](https://tessellate.cmi.ac.in/stems/) competition for Computer Science (Category A & B).

Some tangentially relevant discussion is in the doi: 10.1007/978-3-319-25396-1_9

Comment: On a side note: Relevant problems can be found [https://openclimb.io/practice/#prerequisites] and maybe some [https://web.archive.org/web/20100705084918/http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/phd/comps/]